# AS3 Move to mouse without smoothment

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe

hello i use this code to make player move to mouse, but this is not really way i want it to move, and i cant find anywhere how to get the way i want to.

code works just all fine, but movement is like smooth and when starts or stops moving it like fades in and out like smooth movement and if mouse is farther from character it goes faster, but i dont want that i want character to move at 1 constant speed also i would like to make it go infinity not just where mouse stops but just go directly that way where mouse is pointing.

Thanks for help! :)

code:

```
private var _playerSpeed:Number = 20;   

var dx:Number = parent.mouseX - this.x;
var dy:Number = parent.mouseY - this.y;

this.x += dx / _playerSpeed;
this.y += dy / _playerSpeed;
```

Comment: `if mouse is farther from character it goes faster` what do you expect from that code? Get a calculator, assume `dx` is 300. Since 300 / 20 = 15 here you are telling `this.x` to add (**+=**) 15 pixels per frame of your game's FPS. If your game is 30 FPS that's 450 pixels distance travelled in one second. A lot of distance. Also your `dx` (direction X) is simply minus-ing mouse X-pos from character's X-pos. So assuming `mouseX` = 10 and `this.x` = 200, `10 - 200` =  minus 190... So `-190 / 20` = minus 9.5. How can you add using `+=` for a value that is minus??  Does this even work..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For moving to direction of mouse you need to use **Atan (ArcTangent)**, **Sin** & **Cos** to get angle of mouse pos and move Char in that angle/direction.

If you check the **[Math API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html)**, you'll see **[Atan2](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#atan2())** is what you want.

> Computes and returns the **angle** of the point y/x in radians... the
>   first parameter to atan2 is always the y coordinate.

(code untested in Flash) An example looks like :

```
private var _playerSpeed:Number = 20;   

var dx:Number = parent.mouseX - this.x;
var dy:Number = parent.mouseY - this.y;

//# One of these two is correct for Angle result in your app
var angle:Number = Math.atan2( dy, dx ) * Math.PI / 180; 
//var angle:Number = Math.atan2( dy, dx ) * ( 180 / Math.PI); //# or try this version 

this.x += Math.cos( angle ) * _playerSpeed;  
this.y += Math.sin( angle ) * _playerSpeed;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that you recalculate the speed every time the player moves. As he moves closer to the mouse, since there is less distance, you move slower.

```
private var _playerSpeed:Number = 20;   

var dx:Number = parent.mouseX - this.x;
var dy:Number = parent.mouseY - this.y;
```

Divide dx and dy by the distance to turn them into a fraction (unit vector):

```
var distance:Number = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dx,2)+Math.pow(dy,2));
dx = dx/distance;
dy = dy/distance;
```

Then to find your constant speed multiply the fractions (unit vector) by the speed:

```
dx += dx*playerSpeed;
dy += dy*playerSpeed;
```

This last part is the ONLY PART you should be doing every frame. The first part should only be done once.